# Vlook up repeated values if they meet certain conditions, if not found, vlookup the condition of next repeated value

Tags: excel

I have two sheets for repeated values (**ID**) along with **Start Date** and **End Date**, I want to know if the dates matches certain criteria. The below tables will give an idea of what i'm trying to achieve.

The objective is to find if **ID** has done a task within the **Start Date** and **End Date** from dates found from sheet2. The problem with Vlookup is that it only finds the first occurrence of ID (doesn't continue).

I have tried something like this but doesn't do the job right, because it only finds the first occurrence and checks the conditions:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A2:C8,AND(Sheet2!B2>=Sheet1!B2, Sheet2!C2<=Sheet1!C2),FALSE)
```

**sheet1:**
I want to know if **ID** did a task within specified dates
[image]

**sheet2:**
Contains list of tasks that **ID**s have done
[image]

Comment: If the desired result is just yes/no, then you can use IF and COUNTIFS.

Comment: @BigBen Can you please elaborate more? I want to find the ID and compare each date corresponding to that ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IF` and `COUNTIFS`, something like the following:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(G:G,A2,H:H,">="&B2,I:I,"<="&C2)>0,"Yes","No")
```

[image]